# How to query iTunes lookup API to find a tvOS app?

Tags: app-store-connect, tvos, itunes-store

Looks like the standard iTunes lookup endpoint does not include tvOS apps yet:

https://itunes.apple.com/us/lookup?id=1055205969

This is a valid tvOS app ID, and for Mac/iPad/iPhone apps that endpoint would return a dict of information about the app.

Any ideas on how to query iTunes for this information?

Comment: Did you find a solution to the problem, yet?